# return value from nested sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL and i want the`order_item_wo_id` column to return null if the item does not exist in the nested sql and return the value of a column `oi.cop_workorder_id` if it does.

**How can i accomplish this?**

```sql
SELECT 
    cop.wo_id,
    CASE
     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT oi.cop_workorder_id 
            FROM oseo_orderitem  oi
            WHERE oi.cop_workorder_id = cop.wo_id) THEN 
            oi.cop_workorder_id
     ELSE null
    END AS order_item_wo_id
FROM oseo_cop_wo cop
where cop.wo_id = '123';
```

It looks like the `oi.cop_workorder_id` does not get recognized outside of the nested sql.

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "oi"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, it seems you are overcomplicating this.
Just use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    cop.wo_id,
    oi.cop_workorder_id AS order_item_wo_id
FROM oseo_cop_wo AS cop
    LEFT JOIN oseo_orderitem AS oi
        ON oi.cop_workorder_id = cop.wo_id
WHERE cop.wo_id = '123';
```

Comment: dohh! I always over complicate, that's easy. Keeping things simple takes creativity.

Answer (score 1):

use can use the [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html) function.  It works similar to Oracle's NVL function.  I don't have PostgreSQL available to write and test this, however.

Comment: sorry, from the documentation, i don't see how i can  use this.

Comment: ahhhh, I see, I was a little misdirected by your explanation.  Looks like Justin provided the right solution.